# ASP file with 2 scripts does not load second script

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, web, asp.net-web-api

I have as ASP page, this page reads a xml file and shows the information inside a table.

I need to create a second script just like the first one to read a second xml file and display the info in another table.

i created the script, that i will post below, the page take ages to load, and only the first script loads.

```
<div class="centro">
  <table class="tabela_centro">
    <tr>
      <td class="td_noticias_barra_vertical"></td>
      <td class="td_noticias_toda"
        <%

          response.write (" style=width:950px !important; "" >")

        %>
        <div class="noticias">
          <%

          '--------------------------------------ver quantas noticias estao activas
          '
          dim qt_noticias_activas
          qt_noticias_activas=0
          dim array_noticias_activas()
          dim activo

          Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
          xmlDOM.async = False
          xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
          xmlDOM.Load("c:\temp\noticias.xml")

          for i=1 to 10

          Set itemList = XMLDom.SelectNodes("noticias/noticia" & i)
          For Each itemAttrib In itemList
          activo  =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("activo").text
          if activo="S" then
          redim preserve array_noticias_activas(qt_noticias_activas)
          array_noticias_activas(qt_noticias_activas)=i
          qt_noticias_activas=qt_noticias_activas+1
          end if
          ' response.write activo
          Next
          '    response.write i & "-" & qt_noticias_activas & "-" & array_noticias_activas(0)
          next
          '---------------------------------------------ver qual o minuto actual
          '
          dim minutos
          minutos=minute(now)+60
          ' ----------------------------------------descobrir qual noticia a mostrar
          '
          dim noticia_a_mostrar
          while minutos > qt_noticias_activas
          minutos=minutos - qt_noticias_activas
          wend
          noticia_a_mostrar=array_noticias_activas(minutos -1)

          '-----------------------------------------------------carregar a noticia escolhida
          '
          dim titulo, data, texto, foto1, foto2
          Set itemList = XMLDom.SelectNodes("noticias/noticia" & noticia_a_mostrar)
          For Each itemAttrib In itemList
          data  =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("data").text
          titulo  =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("titulo").text
          foto1  =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("foto1").text
          foto2  =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("foto2").text
          Next

          Set xmlDOM = Nothing
          Set itemList = Nothing

          'response.write titulo & data & foto1 & foto2
          '
          %>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                <div class="noticias_titulo">
                  <%=titulo%>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr_noticias_fotos">
              <td class="td_noticias_fotos1">
                <div class="noticias_foto1">
                  <img  class="foto1" src="<%=foto1%>">
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="td_noticias_fotos2">
                <div class="noticias_foto2">
                  <img class="foto2" src="<%=foto2%>">
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td class="td_servicos_barra_vertical"></td>
      <td style="max-width:35%; vertical-align:top;" class="td_servicos_toda">

        <div id="secstate">
          <div><h3 class="cultura_titulo">Estado de segurança: <span id="span_estado">ALFA<span></h3></div>
        </div>
        <%

      '--------------------------------------ver quantas noticias culturais estao activas
      '
      dim qt_culturas_activas
      qt_culturas_activas=0
      dim array_culturas_activas()
      dim activocult

      Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
      xmlDOM.async = False
      xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
      xmlDOM.Load("c:\temp\culturas.xml")

      for i=1 to 10

      Set itemList = XMLDom.SelectNodes("culturas/cultura" & i)
      For Each itemAttrib In itemList
      activocult  =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("activo").text
      if activo="S" then
      redim preserve array_culturas_activas(qt_culturas_activas)
      array_culturas_activas(qt_culturas_activas)=i
      qt_culturas_activas=qt_culturas_activas+1
      end if
      ' response.write activocult
      Next
      '    response.write i & "-" & qt_culturas_activas & "-" & array_culturas_activas(0)
      next
      '---------------------------------------------ver qual o minuto actual
      '
      dim minutoscult
      minutoscult=minute(now)+60
      ' ----------------------------------------descobrir qual noticia de cultura a mostrar
      '
      dim cultura_a_mostrar
      while minutoscult > qt_culturas_activas
      minutoscult=minutoscult - qt_culturas_activas
      wend
      cultura_a_mostrar=array_culturas_activas(minutoscult -1)

      '-----------------------------------------------------carregar a noticia de cultura escolhida
      '
      dim titulocult, datacult, foto1cult
      Set itemList = XMLDom.SelectNodes("culturas/cultura" & cultura_a_mostrar)
      For Each itemAttrib In itemList
      datacult  =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("data").text
      titulocult  =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("titulo").text
      foto1cult  =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("foto1").text
      Next

      Set xmlDOM = Nothing
      Set itemList = Nothing

      'response.write titulocult & datacult & foto1cult
      '
      %>
        <div class="cultura_titulo"><h4><%=titulocult%></h4></div>
        <div class="cultura_foto">

          <img style="width:90%" src="<%=foto1cult%>">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table><!--fim da tabela do centro todo -->
</div>
```

Can you guys help me out a bit? i was asked to complete another developer job... and i am not really inside the ASP language.

Regards

roberto

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have found my mistake, in the line `if activo="S" then` of the second script, it should be `if activocult="S" then`.

thanks for your time